# Função Incompleta

Tags: javascript

Preciso saber onde está o erro na seguinte função:

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo) {
  let quantidade= ????;
  for (let mes=0; mes< umPeriodo.length; mes++) {
    ????
  }
  return quantidade;
}
```

Eu tentei completar, mas não consigo, segue o meu código:

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo) {
  let quantidade= 0;
  for (let mes=0; mes< umPeriodo.length; mes++) {
    quantidade = umPeriodo[mes]
   
    
  }
  return quantidade;
}
```

Essa questão é de um exercício e não consigo descobrir o erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Comment: é difícil saber o erro quando não sabemos o proposito.

Comment: Refere-se a que tipo de erro? Erro que aparece na consola ou simplesmente não está a ser executado direito? "quantidade = umPeriodo[mês]" deveria de ser "quantidade += umPeriodo[mes]"

Comment: o exercicio pede apenas para completar a função, ai não consegui :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De maneira completar a função necessitaria de saber o que é considerado um mês com lucro, como não entendi vou deixar nesta forma:

```
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo) {
    let quantidade = 0;
    for (let mes=0; mes< umPeriodo.length; mes++) {
        if(*houver lucro em umPeriodo[mês]*) {
            quantidade = quantidade + 1 (ou quantidade += 1)
        }
    }
    return quantidade;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado André, era isso mesmo, agora entendi o erro, valeu!